# Using array and iteration or jquery each() to open a new dialog and close any others that are open

Tags: jquery, arrays, each

In this example I have 5 dialogs that can be opened by hovering over thumbnail images and text links. An open dialog does not close as soon as the cursor leaves the thumbnail image or text - it stays open until the cursor moves over another thumbnail or link. Before opening a new dialog, the function checks if any of the others are visible, and closes them, and if the one that it is about to open is already visible, then it does nothing. Everything is working fine, but I plan to have up to 25 dialogs, so I want to shorten the code. Can someone show me how to turn this into an array and iteration, or jquery each() function. I'm sure it's pretty straightforward but I'm a novice and couldn't figure it out from the documentation.

```
function Close01() {if($(vid01).is(":visible")){vid01.dialog('close');}}
function Close02() {if($(vid02).is(":visible")){vid02.dialog('close');}}
function Close03() {if($(vid03).is(":visible")){vid03.dialog('close');}}
function Close04() {if($(vid04).is(":visible")){vid04.dialog('close');}}
function Close05() {if($(vid05).is(":visible")){vid05.dialog('close');}}

function Open01() {if($(vid01).is(":visible")===false){ vid01.dialog('open'); vid01.load(content01);}}
function Open02() {if($(vid02).is(":visible")===false){ vid02.dialog('open'); vid02.load(content02);}}
function Open03() {if($(vid03).is(":visible")===false){ vid03.dialog('open'); vid03.load(content03);}}
function Open04() {if($(vid04).is(":visible")===false){ vid04.dialog('open'); vid04.load(content04);}}
function Open05() {if($(vid05).is(":visible")===false){ vid05.dialog('open'); vid05.load(content05);}}

function hovIn01() {Close02(); Close03(); Close04(); Close05(); Open01()}
function hovIn02() {Close01(); Close03(); Close04(); Close05(); Open02()}
function hovIn03() {Close01(); Close02(); Close04(); Close05(); Open03()}
function hovIn04() {Close01(); Close02(); Close03(); Close05(); Open04()}
function hovIn05() {Close01(); Close02(); Close03(); Close04(); Open05()}

function hovOutDoNothing() {}

$('.gallery-01').hoverIntent(hovIn01, hovOutDoNothing);
$('.gallery-02').hoverIntent(hovIn02, hovOutDoNothing);
$('.gallery-03').hoverIntent(hovIn03, hovOutDoNothing);
$('.gallery-04').hoverIntent(hovIn04, hovOutDoNothing);
$('.gallery-05').hoverIntent(hovIn05, hovOutDoNothing);
```

Comment: Ugh, all that repetition, please learn the [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself) principle! Write a single function that takes an argument.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need an array. Just give all the dialogs a class (e.g. `popupstyle`). Then you can close all of them except the current one with:

```
$(".popupstyle:not(#"+currentId+")").dialog("close");
```

Comment: Thanks, that looks nice! The dialogs have a style called "popupstyle". I added this code:
    var currentId = $(this).attr('id');
     $(".popupstyle:not(currentID)").dialog("close");
But they are staying open. Is there something else I need to add?

Comment: You need to concatenate the ID like I did in my answer. Variables aren't replaced inside strings.

Comment: Is this the correct syntax?: var thisId = $(this).attr('id');

$(".popupstyle:not(#"+thisID+")").dialog("close");

Comment: If it's the same as my answer, then I think so.

Comment: The syntax looks correct but all my dialogs have stopped opening.

Comment: Can you make an executable snippet that contains the HTML and your Javascript? It's hard to tell what you're doing wrong from this.

Comment: OK, will be back with more tomorrow!

Comment: Please post the code here. Use the snippets editor to create an executable demonstration.

Comment: And StackOverflow doesn't use bbcode, get rid of `[link]...[/link]`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var arrayOfIds = [];

function closeDialog(dialogId){
    //close the dialog whose ID has been passed
}

function openDialog(dialogId){
    //open the dialog whose ID has been passed
}

function hoverIn(dialogId){
    $.each(arrayOfIds,function(key,val){
         // close everyone else except for the one whose ID has been passed
    });
}
```